# Discord.py Помогите, сделал on_message, и бот перестал реагировать на команды

Tags: python, discord

Помогите, сделал on_message, и бот перестал реагировать на команды,и нету ошибок в консоле, подскажите что делать, вот мой код:

```
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.id == 1008040239023018005:
            await message.create_thread(name="Идея для Discord", auto_archive_duration=4320)
        # rest of your code goes here

        # notice the indentation layer. This needs to be at the top layer of your function
        await self.bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Пропишите это в самом начале ивента on_message, так бот будет рассматривать сообщение сначала как команду, а уже потом как сообщение

Также стоит убедиться есть ли у бота право читать сообщения и такое намерение (intents = discord.Intents.all(), при создании клиента бота)

В вашем случаи это:

```
async def on_message(self, message):

    await bot.process_commands(message) # возможно вместо bot надо self, я не знаю, что здесь объект бота, нужно больше кода

    if message.channel.id == 1008040239023018005:
        await message.create_thread(name="Идея для Discord", auto_archive_duration=4320)
    # rest of your code goes here

    # notice the indentation layer. This needs to be at the top layer of your function
    await self.bot.process_commands(message)
```